# Building a Java EE 6 project, with a swing client using Maven

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish-3

I am trying to recreate an existing project with Maven (any IDE is ok, but mainly Netbeans), and I'm a bit confused about the best way to do this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Currently I have an Enterprise application with the following components:

- Web application (some jsps, servlets).
- Ejb project
- Client project (Swing application / applet)
- Common project (Contains common files used by the applet and the Web app).

The problem is the packaging and dependencies, currently the Client (Applet) jar is packaged within the Web application, so that when the web app is deployed, the users can access the applet via their browser.

Is there any similar existing archetype for this, or does it require heavy customization ?

Oh, and I am using Glassfish 3.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, for me it looks like you need multi module maven project. In that case there will be no single archetype that will fulfill your needs.

When it comes to "the Client (Applet) jar is packaged within the Web application" you can use maven-dependency-plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its goal:

> **dependency:copy** - takes a list of artifacts defined in the plugin configuration section and copies them to a specified location, renaming them or stripping the version if desired. This goal can resolve the artifacts from remote repositories if they don't exist in local.